How to properly manage context and cleanup in asynchronous Python code with contextlib and asyncio?
I’ve been working with asynchronous programming in Python using asyncio, and I encountered a problem when trying to manage resources that need to be cleaned up properly, even in the face of exceptions or cancellations.
I understand that contextlib provides tools for managing resources with synchronous context managers, but I’m unsure how to properly extend this to asynchronous context managers and ensure resources are always cleaned up.
Here’s an example of what I’m trying to achieve:
import asyncio
import contextlib

class AsyncResource:
    async def __aenter__(self):
        print("Acquiring resource")
        # Simulate acquiring resource
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        return self

    async def __aexit__(self, exc_type, exc, tb):
        print("Releasing resource")
        # Simulate releasing resource
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

@contextlib.asynccontextmanager
async def async_resource_manager():
    resource = AsyncResource()
    await resource.__aenter__()
    try:
        yield resource
    finally:
        await resource.__aexit__(None, None, None)

async def main():
    async with async_resource_manager() as resource:
        print("Using resource")
        # Simulate some work
        await asyncio.sleep(2)

asyncio.run(main())

This works as expected, but I’m wondering:
Is this the idiomatic way to handle asynchronous context managers in Python?
How can I ensure that resources are properly cleaned up in the event of an exception or task cancellation?
Are there any best practices or common pitfalls to be aware of when using contextlib.asynccontextmanager with asyncio?
Any insights or examples would be greatly appreciated!

async with is for asynchronous context managers what with is for synchronous (regular) context managers. It is used in exactly the same way, but instead it is two keywords instead of one:
async with AsyncResource() as resource:
  yield resource

A context manager is any object instance that has __enter__() and __exit__(), or __aenter__() and __aexit__() That's all. Any such object, including instances of your very own AsyncResource can be used immediately using with or async with.
contextlib.contextmanager and contextlib.asynccontextmanager exist to convert a generator (a function with a yield statement) into a context manager with the correct methods. But, AsyncResource already has these methods, so there is no need for these decorators here.
To simplify your code, you may remove async_resource_manager() and replace async with async_resource_manager() as resource: with async with AsyncResource() as resource:.
See also: Why do we need `async for` and `async with`?
